# Google Cloud Kubernetes Load Balancer Service: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: java, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing

I have this problem that's driving me insane. I have two deployment and two service yaml files created by kompose convert from a docker-compose. The app that I'm trying to run in Google Cloud is a Spring Boot web app with a mariadb backend. After I apply the four yamls with kubectl, I expose the frontend deployment (on port 8081) by running

Comment: Pasting your yamls would help debugging, but as a first check, try `kubectl get svc -n {your-namespace}` and see what service type and IP has been assigned to your service.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru Why don't you expose your `web-app` service directly as `LoadBalancer`? As you can see in the [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service#services_of_type_loadbalancer), you only need to include `type: LoadBalancer` in your `web-app-service.yaml` service `spec` definition and modify your external `port` to `80`, and it should be able to serve your deployment without further configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

TL;DR for anyone coming to this question via search:

OP's service was a ClusterIP and not LoadBalancer. Setting this as LoadBalancer still did not fix issue. Checking logs of pod determined code was unable to connect to DB, so never actually started up successfully.

---

Output from OP:

```
kubectl get svc -n default

NAME          TYPE          CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)       AGE
kubernetes    ClusterIP     10.72.0.1    <none>         443/TCP       147m
load-balancer LoadBalancer  10.72.15.246 34.69.204.138  80:30870/TCP  86s
mysqldb       ClusterIP     10.72.3.186  <none>         3308/TCP      3m20s
web-app       ClusterIP     10.72.13.41  <none>         8081/TCP      3m19s
```

Please share those in your question, making sure to prepend "```" before and after each yaml to preserve formatting

Now, a few points.

1. You specified you have service yamls. If you have a yaml that describes a service such as a `LoadBalancer`, you shouldn't need to `kubectl expose` afterwards, as your yaml *should* have done that for you.
2. Assuming the service named "load-balancer" is the one you have created via your yamls, the IP:port combination you should be using is `34.69.204.138:80`. What IP have you been trying to access? Are you trying to access this IP and port? Or a different one?

---

UPDATE

Based on the pasted yamls, I see this:

In your docker-compose yaml:

```
  web-app:
    build: .
    image: mihaialexandruteodor/featherwriter
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    expose:
      - "8081"
```

This is exposing port 8081 and connecting it to the underlying container.

This is reflected in the service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  ...
  name: web-app
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "8081"
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: web-app
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

However, I do not see a service called "`web-app`" in your listing. It's possible therefore, you may have deployed it into a different namespace.

Try `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces` and see where the service "`web-app`" is. Find the IP from that, the port should be 8081 and you can then do `x.x.x.x:8081` to access the service.

---

UPDATE 2

The `web-app` service is of type `ClusterIP` ([documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer)) which cannot be accessed outside of the cluster, you need to change the service to be a `LoadBalancer` type, or use [port-forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/).

To make the service a LoadBalancer, change the service yaml as follows (documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer)):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.1 (HEAD)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: mysqldb
  name: mysqldb
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "3308"
      port: 3308
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: mysqldb
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This will provision a service that will have an external IP you can use.

Alternatively, use port forwarding to connect a local port with the port being listened on by the service:

```
kubectl port-forward -n {namespace} svc/web-app 8081:8081
```

Then you can use `localhost:8081` to connect to your service. This option does not require an externally-accessible endpoint, but you will need to run the port forward command (and have it active) each time you want to access the service via the localhost endpoint.

If you want to be able to access the service from somewhere outside of your cluster, that is not your local machine, and is not within the same cluster, you will need to use a LoadBalancer service type.

---

UPDATE 3

Right, I can't build that Dockerfile as I do not have the `src` folder, but I can run the image from `mihaialexandruteodor/featherwriter`, and can see it is indeed listening on 8081

```
Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
```

so the next thing to see is see if there's any issues with the pod functionality itself. First check the pod status:

```
kubectl get pods -n {namespace}
```

The pod should be called `web-app-xxxxx` where `xxxxx` is a random sequence of letters and numbers.

Is the web-app pod running? Does it have a restart counter that is not zero like some of the pods in my prometheus namespace:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n prometheus
NAME                                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
alertmanager-prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager-0   2/2     Running   0          3h51m
prometheus-grafana-66cb8bcf4f-428d8                      3/3     Running   0          3h51m
prometheus-kube-prometheus-operator-749fc8899b-dnvft     1/1     Running   0          3h51m
prometheus-kube-state-metrics-77698656df-btq4k           1/1     Running   20         3h51m
prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0       2/2     Running   0          3h51m
prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-jj9z5                1/1     Running   30         3h51m
prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-lbk6p                1/1     Running   0          3h51m
prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-vqfhk                1/1     Running   20         3h51m
```

Next get the logs from the pods like so:

```
kubectl logs -n {namespace} web-app-xxxxx
```

See if you can find any errors.

My hunch, given that we've connected everything through on 8081 and Tomcat is indeed running on 8081, is that the spring app is crashing repeatedly and Kubernetes is restarting it, the app then fails again, and it tries again over and over, eventually failing into a `CrashLoopBackOff` state where Kubernetes will delay restarting by a longer period.

Comment: I used to have the web-app defined as a load balancer service, now I just expose the web-app deployment. I tried to access  34.69.204.138:80, this is where I got connection refused.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on the additional information you have provided

Comment: isn't the web-app service the very last one in the listing? Sorry, I'm a bit confused. I edited the question to include the result from --all-namespaces

Comment: Ah, I missed that line. I have updated the answer more based on the additional information.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I really appreciate you taking the time! I had the web-app service as a LoadBalancer service before, but perhaps I wasn't doing it right. Will test the port forwarding and let you know how it goes

Comment: UPDATE: Adding type: LoadBalancer to the spec section created the Load Balancer service with external IP, but it still gives me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Port forwarding displayed "Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8081 -> 8081" and kept the cursor blinking, opening a new tab and trying localhost:8081 gave me the old ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED too :(

Comment: That seems to indicate the container is not listening on 8081. Even though we're connecting everything through to the container on port 8081. If it's not listening on that port (maybe it's listening on 8080 instead?) then you will get the connection refused error

Comment: what should I change in the yamls to make sure I'm listening to the right port ?

Comment: It's not the yamls you need to check, you should check the actual container. Could you share the Dockerfile you used to generate the `mihaialexandruteodor/featherwriter` image? (Redact anything that is confidential)

Comment: nothing confidential :) I added it to the post

Comment: Updated answer with more information

Comment: updated, please have a look

Comment: Are there any log entries after the ones you posted? For me, I get a stacktrace, but that's probably because I'm not connected a MySQL. Does the log entries hang at that last line?

Comment: please see the answer above, it's too long to include in the main post

Comment: could it be an application.properties problem in the way I'm connecting to the database ?

Comment: Bingo. It's unable to connect to the database, therefore the application never fully comes up. And since it never fully comes up, Tomcat never really actually starts listening, as it never finishes the startup process. Fix the communication to the DB issue and this should fix the main issue :)